# Good Practice for selecting the "Compile with" API option in Android Applications

Tags: android

When creating an Android App i have to select the "Compile with" API option. The help of that option says that ive to use typically the latest version, or the first version that supports all the APIs i want to use.

I have the following questions:

*as far i as understand, the newest APIs "contains or support" (not sure if its because of the use of Android Support Library) the previous APIs. This makes unnecessary to download a previous API to compile an android project which has some previous API requirements? 

For example, lets say im gonna create an application whose "Target SDK" is GingerBread, is it a good practice to work with the latest API (Jelly Beans) as the "compile API" in this scenario? I suppose that the problem could be to use an API that is only available for JellyBeans but Lint can help to solve that.

*If the above question is true, I only need to download previous APIs only for running the emulator with those versions?

Thanks!

Comment: Rule of thumb: Release your app with the highest possible API. Test it with every API you intend to support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> as far i as understand, the newest APIs "contains or support" (not sure if its because of the use of Android Support Library) the previous APIs.

Generally speaking, this is correct.

> This makes unnecessary to download a previous API to compile an android project which has some previous API requirements?

Generally speaking, this too is correct.

> For example, lets say im gonna create an application whose "Target SDK" is GingerBread, is it a good practice to work with the latest API (Jelly Beans) as the "compile API" in this scenario?

There is nothing wrong in doing so, as long as you have your `android:minSdkVersion` set to what you want.

> I suppose that the problem could be to use an API that is only available for JellyBeans but Lint can help to solve that.

Correct.

> If the above question is true, I only need to download previous APIs only for running the emulator with those versions?

Correct. Specifically, you are looking for the "...System Image" entries in the SDK Manager, at least the ARM and x86 ones.

Comment: thanks dude! ive seen many of your answers and have helped me a lot